# Programmatically set selected values - Mat Select Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, drop-down-menu, angular-material

I have tried to set the selected value of a Mat Select using typescript. I have the following code

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select formControlName="students" multiple>
    <mat-option [value]="item.studentId"
                *ngFor="let item of listOfStudents" >
            {{item.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Typescript

```
this.studentService.getStudents().pipe(
       takeUntil(componentDestroyed(this))
     ).subscribe(response => {
          this.listOfStudents = _.orderBy(response, 'name', 'asc');
          const selectedStudentsData = this.listOfStudents.filter(student=> Number(student['studentId']===101)|| Number(student['studentId']===102));
          this.studentForm.controls['students'] = new FormControl(selectedStudentsData);
     }
);
```

But it is not working. How to programmatically set selected values in Mat Select?

Comment: You can use `[(ngModel)] = "selectedValue"` pattern.. like `<mat-select #mySel multiple [(ngModel)]= "selectedValues">`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-knzeco?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html you can find example in this stackbliz link

Comment: it is working as i expected.

Comment: what have you changed in your code in order to work it right?

Answer (score 2):

Filter returns an array not element. And for updating values, you do not need to create a new instance of `FormControl`

```
const selectedStudentsData = this.listOfStudents
  .filter(student => Number(student['studentId']===101) || Number(student['studentId']===102));
    
// Use setValue method to set the value
this.studentForm.controls['students'].setValue(selectedStudentsData);

// And finally validate the form
this.studentForm.updateValueAndValidity()
```

Comment: Property 'updateAndValidate' does not exist on type 'FormGroup'.

Comment: Sorry, typo, fixed it